# What is the difference between 电视 and 电视上?

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, adverbs

In the following two sentences:

```
电视说今天很晴朗，不过下午下雨了。
电视上说今天的天气会很晴朗，今天一整天都很晴朗。
```

Why does the first sentence not use `上` but the second sentence does? Is there any difference between `电视` and `电视上`?

I think the meaning is the same - i.e. both mean "The TV says..." or "According to the TV...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as a native speaker, I would say there is no rigid rule for the usage under consideration. Both sentences precisely express what you would like to express.

So yes, they are identical in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are correct, and they are the same.
I would say the slight difference between them is that first sentence more colloquial than second one.

they are in English should be:

```
TV said ...
TV show/display ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are correct, with no big difference. That 上 means "on":

电视说... - The TV says...

电视上说... - **On** the TV it says...